# HTTP Load Balancer ClientIP affinity not working

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I can't seem to get the session affinity behavior in the GCP load balancer to work properly. My test has been as follows:

- I have a Container Engine cluster with 2 node pools (different zones) with 2 nodes each.
- I have a deployment which is set to replica: 8, and it's (almost) evenly spread between the 4 nodes.
- I have a service exposed as follows (ips redacted)

  ```
  Name:           svc-foo
  Namespace:      default
  Labels:         app=foo
  Selector:       app=foo
  Type:           NodePort
  IP:         ....
  Port:           <unset> 8080/TCP
  NodePort:       <unset> 31015/TCP
  Endpoints:      ...:8080,...:8080,...:8080 + 5 more...
  Session Affinity:   ClientIP
  No events.
  ```
- I have a load balancer with a backend service that has 2 backends pointed at port 31015. It has a healthcheck which passes and a route to get to that backend service.
- Finally, I have the Session affinity set to ClientIP on that backend service as well.

After curling a route and checking the logs in stackdriver, I see `container.googleapis.com/pod_name:` in the metadata of the logs with a bunch of different pod names. In the Kubernetes ui, I also see that all the pods have a little cpu spike, indicating I'm alternating and hitting each one. A weird part is that in GCP, when I look at the monitoring of the backend service, the graph shows me requests per second only to one of the pools (even though the logs and cpu graphs from k8s show the other pool being hit as well).

Comment: Did you create the load balancer in GCE separately instead of relying on Kubernetes to create it for your service automatically? http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/load-balancer/

Comment: It was created manually in GCP because I needed an HTTP (L7) load balancer.

Comment: IIUC, L3 load balancer automatically enables L7 load balancing, since HTTP is on top of TCP.